# Mean value inequality for polynomials in $\mathbb C$

Tags: calculus

Is mean value inequality true for polynomials in $\mathbb C$? I mean: let $P\in\mathbb C[z]$. For all $x,y\in\mathcal D:=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid |z|\le 1\}$, does one have
$$|P(x)-P(y)|\le\max_{\theta\in\mathcal D}|P'(\theta)|\times|x-y|?$$

Thanks in advance for any answer and proof.

Comment: I don't see any benefit in restricting to either polynomials or the closed unit disc.  This is true for any holomorphic function $P : U \to \mathbb{C}$ where $U$ is a domain and $\mathcal{D} \subset U$ is a convex set.  This effectively is by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the [ML-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma)

Comment: This can be proven for holomorphic functions in a domain without any appeal to integration theory though it takes a little work-- e.g. consider ex 11.67 (p. 274) of Koerner's *A Companion to Analysis*.